# React not saving output of SetTimeout

Tags: reactjs, settimeout, use-state

I can't figure out what's going on here.  I have this code

```
setIdleEvent(setTimeout(onIdle, idleTimeout)); 
console.log('idleEvent', idleEvent);
```

`idleEvent` is a state, defined as
`const [idleEvent, setIdleEvent] = useState<NodeJS.Timeout>();`
After executing this code, `idleEvent` is undefined.

So I tried this

```
const foo = setTimeout(onIdle, idleTimeout);
console.log('foo:', foo); 
setIdleEvent(foo);
console.log('idleEvent', idleEvent);
```

Foo has a numeric value, but `idleEvent` is still undefined. What's going on?

[image]

Comment: The code is working, you just have your log statement in a spot where it isn't useful. Calling `setIdleEvent` does not change the value of the local const `idleEvent` (it's a const, it *can't* change). Instead, it instructs react to rerender the component. On the next render, a new const will be created with the new value, but your log statement in the previous render has no access to that. If you'd like to verify that the component is rerendering, put a log statement in the body of the component.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm relatively new to react and still learning some of these nuances